# How to Enable Hardware Accelerate for View?

Tags: android

How to Enable Hardware Accelerate for View?
I tried to set

```
 imvTopNumber.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
```

and also

```
<application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" ...>
```

But it is not work. I tested on Nexus 7 (API 16)
It always return false when check `isHardwareAccelerated();`
Please help me!

Comment: What didn't work?  Did you get an error message?

Comment: Note: You currently cannot enable hardware acceleration at the view level as mentioned in http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html#controlling   You can try enabling hardware on the window inside the activity or directly on activity

Comment: I still have this issue, any update about that?